# how to use one function for multiple file upload buttons

Tags: javascript

I have four upload buttons with their respective ids.

```html
<div class="card-body">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="mainDiv" align="right">
                    <progress id="uploader" value="0" max="100">0%</progress>
                    <input type="file" id="fileButton" value="upload" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="mainDiv" align="right">
                    <progress id="uploader" value="0" max="100">0%</progress>
                    <input type="file" id="fileButton" value="upload" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="mainDiv" align="right">
                    <progress id="uploader2" value="0" max="100">0%</progress>
                    <input type="file" id="fileButton2" value="upload" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="mainDiv" align="right">
                    <progress id="uploader3" value="0" max="100">0%</progress>
                    <input type="file" id="fileButton3" value="upload" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am able to upload to firebase storage through one button with this function

```
$("#fileButton").on('change', function(e) {
    var file = evt.target.files[0];
    var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('img/' + file.name);
    var task = storageRef.put(file);
    task.on('state_changed', function progress(snapshot) {
        var percentage = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
        uploader.value = percentage;
    }, function error(err) {

    }, function complete() {

    });
})
```

the function works great but what I want to do is to prevent duplicating functions. I want to use that function for each of the upload input and uploader status. 
I tried this but it does not work

```
 $("#fileButton0", "#fileButton1", "#fileButton2", "#fileButton3").on('change'
```

how could I use the same function for each of the upload and uploader?

here is the jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/dhs8g7fb/

Comment: Use a class name, something like `file-button`. Then you can just call `$(".file-button").on('change')`

Comment: You can add a class to all of your inputs and then bind the onchange event to that class

Comment: How you access them is secondary. You could just as easily do `$(".mainDiv input[type='file']").on("change"...`, and it would work with what you currently have. Aside from a firebase error, I have this working: https://jsfiddle.net/snowMonkey/jz17hdga/2/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working code !

```js
const FileBtns = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='file'][id]");
FileBtns.forEach(function(btn) {
  btn.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
    console.log(this);
    var file = e.target.files[0];
    var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('img/' + file.name);
    var task = storageRef.put(file);
    task.on('state_changed', function progress(snapshot) {
      var percentage = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
      uploader.value = percentage;

    }, function error(err) {
      //Some error task
    }, function complete() {
      console.log("we dit");
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="card-body">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6">
        <div class="mainDiv" align="right">
          <progress id="uploader0" value="0" max="100">0%</progress>
          <input type="file" id="fileButton0" value="upload" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6">
        <div class="mainDiv" align="right">
          <progress id="uploader1" value="0" max="100">0%</progress>
          <input type="file" id="fileButton1" value="upload" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div><br>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6">
        <div class="mainDiv" align="right">
          <progress id="uploader2" value="0" max="100">0%</progress>
          <input type="file" id="fileButton2" value="upload" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6">
        <div class="mainDiv" align="right">
          <progress id="uploader3" value="0" max="100">0%</progress>
          <input type="file" id="fileButton3" value="upload" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```